# Как очистить холст навсегда, clearRect()

Tags: javascript, canvas

Суть проблемы: рисую линии на холсте, по клику мышки. Весь холст очищаю clearRect(). Если, после этого, нарисовать еще линию, то появляются все нарисованные ранее. Такое ощущение, что clearRect() просто закрашивает линии белым, а не удаляет их.

```js
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var coords = [];//массив для хранения координат мыши первого клика
canvas.onclick = function(event){
  var x = event.offsetX;
  var y = event.offsetY;
  if (coords.length == 0) {
    coords.push(x);
    coords.push(y);
    console.log("Первый клик:", coords);
  } else {
    console.log("Второй клик:", coords);
    context.moveTo(coords[0], coords[1]);
    context.lineTo(x,y);
    context.stroke();
  }
}

var clear = document.getElementById("clear");
clear.onclick = function(){
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.clearRect(0,0,250,380);
  coords.splice(0,coords.length);
  console.log("Очистка ",coords);

}
```

```html
    <canvas id="canvas" width="250" height="380"></canvas>
    <button type="button" id="clear">Очистить</button>
```

Как очистить холст навсегда?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что контур надо закрывать за собой:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/closePath

```js
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var coords = [];//массив для хранения координат мыши первого клика
canvas.onclick = function(event){
  var x = event.offsetX;
  var y = event.offsetY;
  if (coords.length == 0) {
    coords.push(x);
    coords.push(y);
    //console.log("Первый клик:", coords);
  } else {
    //console.log("Второй клик:", coords);
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(coords[0], coords[1]);
    context.lineTo(x,y);
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();
  }
}

var clear = document.getElementById("clear");
clear.onclick = function(){
  context.clearRect(0,0,250,380);
  coords.splice(0,coords.length);
  //console.log("Очистка ",coords);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="clear">Очистить</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="250" height="380"></canvas>
```

Comment: Так я его не открывал, чтобы закрывать)). Спасибо, за подсказку)

Comment: Заметил такую штуку, что холст затирается навсегда, если ему изменить параметры ширины или высоты. Хотя, по всей видимости, он просто новый создается)