# При нажатии на фигуру canvas удаляется блок, а цвет переходит на другой.JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, canvas

```
    var currentPos = 0;
let gameStatus = false
let score = document.getElementById('score');

function drawRect(context, xPos, yPos, color) {
    context.fillRect(xPos, yPos, 20, 20);
     context.fillStyle = color;
}

function randomInteger(min, max) {
    var rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1)
    rand = Math.round(rand);
    return rand;
  }

  function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color
  }
function generateRects(count) {

    let rects = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        let rect = {}
        rect.xPos = randomInteger(0, 640)
        rect.yPos = 0
        rect.yPos = 0        
        rect.color = getRandomColor(); 
        rect.speed = randomInteger(1,2); 
        rects.push(rect);
    }

    return rects
}

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
      y: evt.clientY - rect.top
    };
  }

let rects = generateRects(10);

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
  for(let i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
      if(mousePos.x >= rects[i].xPos && mousePos.x <= rects[i].xPos + 20 && mousePos.y >= rects[i].yPos && mousePos.y <= rects[i].yPos + 20) {  
            rects.splice(i,1);    
        // rects[i].color = 'yellow';
        console.log(rects[i-1])
         score.innerHTML = +score.innerHTML + 1    
      }
  }
}, false);

function animate() {  
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientWidth);
  for(let i = 0; i < rects.length; i++) {
    drawRect(ctx, rects[i].xPos, rects[i].yPos, rects[i].color)
     rects[i].yPos += rects[i].speed;
    if(rects[i].yPos > canvas.clientHeight) {
        rects[i].yPos = 0
    }
  }
  gameStatus && requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', function() {
    score.innerHTML=0;
    rects = generateRects(10);
    gameStatus = true;
    animate();
}, false)

document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click', function() {
    rects = []
    gameStatus = false
    score.innerHTML=0;
}, false)
```

Comment: Нигде не заметил у Вас открытия и закрытия контура. Может у Вас такая же проблема, как у меня была?https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/742400/Как-очистить-холст-навсегда-clearrect

Comment: И мне кажется, Вам нужно вопрос уточнить: написать ожидаемое действие + html добавить

Comment: Вы нам хвастаетесь кодом? Или что ?